# Echo progress bar for while external process executing and take STDOUT when it done

Tags: perl

How I can echo a progress bar while an external process is executing and capture its STDOUT when it's done, using only standard modules. And not using fork?

1. Run external process, something like: `` @array = `ls -l`; ``
2. While it executing, do printing progress bar, like: `print '.';`
3. Capture STDOUT of the process into array, when it done
4. Continue works main script

I'm reading about `IPC::Open2`, `IPC::Open3`, but I don't understand how to use them for this task. Maybe it's not the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried googling "perl progress bar"? I am finding lots of answers for that.

Comment: Yes, I searched, but what is found is only for synchronous code (or with fork). I need to wait for an unmanaged external process to finish

Comment: Your question will likely get closed, because software recommendations are off topic. What you might do is write about one of those solutions, for example Term::ProgressBar, show the code, and ask for help fixing the issues.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for can be implemented with `$SIG{ALARM}`, see documentation for [alarm](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm).

Comment: Other option would be to open `ls -l` process as a file handle, read line by line and output `.` for predefined number of read lines. -- see [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open).

Comment: Polar Bear, ls -l it is example, real process may not give output whle it not finished. 
Okay, it may be closed... Anyway, Thank's for replies!

Comment: Well, then use `$SIG{ALRM}` as alternative.

Comment: And...%% How I may use $SIG{ALRM} for waiting on finishing process ? I don't need to kill the process, only wait to completion and taking it's output. I need googling for it solution... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps OP is looking for something of next kind just to indicate that external process is running.

Define a handler for `$SIG{ALRM}` and set `alarm 1` to run handler every second. Once process complete reset `alarm 0` to turn off alarm handler.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $ls_l;      # variable to store output of external command
$| = 1;        # unbuffered output

$SIG{ALRM} = \&handler;
alarm 1;       # run handler every second

say 'Running sig_alarm_sleep';
$ls_l=`./sig_alarm_sleep`;
say ' done';

alarm 0;

my @fields = qw(rwx count user group size month day time name);
my @lines = split("\n",$ls_l);
my(@array);

for( @lines ) {
    my $x->@{@fields} = split(' ',$_);
    push @array, $x;
}

say Dumper(\@array);

exit 0;

sub handler {
    print '.';
    $SIG{ALRM} = \&handler;
    alarm 1;
}
```

Bash script `sig_alarm_sleep` sample

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

sleep 20
ls -al
```

Comment: I've added a block which processes output of `ls -l` to create an array of hash references for each field of output -- just for fun.

Answer (score 2):

What do you have so far? If you have having trouble with the interprocess communication, forget about the progress bar for the moment and ask just about that.

You can't really have a progress bar for something that has an indeterminate end. If you don't know how much input you will read, you don't know what fraction of it you have read. People tend to think of progress bars as a representation of fraction of work done, just not activity. That is, unless you use macOS and understand that "less than one minute" means "more than three hours". ;)

I tend to do something simple, where I output a dot every so often. I don't know how many dots I'll see, but I know that I'll see new ones.

```
$|++; # unbuffer stdout to see dots as they are output

while( <$fh> ) {
    print '.' if $. % $chunk_size;  # $. is the line number
    print "\n[$.] " if $. % $chunk_size * $row_length;
    ...
    }
```

That `$fh` can be anything that you want to read from, including a pipe. [perlopentut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut#Opening-Pipes) has examples of reading from external processes. Those are doing a fork, though. And, the other modules will fork as well. What's the constraint that makes you think you can't use fork?

You can get more fancy with your display by using curses and other things (a carriage return is handy :), but I'm not inclined to type those out.

Comment: OP on my comment indicated that process will not output anything, my understanding of his question is that he is looking for something like a mark per some predefined period of time. Some form of analogy of second arrow on the wall clock while something is cooking on a stove -- just to indicate that program is working.

Comment: I said wrong about progressbar, probably. Representation of fraction of work done is not what me need. I wanted to display dots in the sense of "wait, wait, your command is still running, wait" :) If nothing will appear in <$fh> then main script will just synchronly wait for the external command to return "it completed". Thus, nothing can not displayed on the screen at that time. Imagine that the external process "is sleeping" (command may bу likу  this 'sleep 3m; echo "all done"'), and all this time when it sleeps, I need to print "wait, wait".

Comment: Polar Bear, you are absolutely right!)  - "just to indicate that program is working"